# How to make table fit in mobile view

Tags: html, css, responsive

I am an HTML/CSS Noob and this is my first time making a website. The issue I can not seem to figure out is how I can get my table to "fit" in mobile view. As you can see the table does cuts off at the bottom and I want to have the entire table fit in the mobile view.

Normal View

[image: Table Normal View]

Table Mobile view

[image: Table Mobile view]

```css
table {
    font-family: 'Pathway Gothic One', sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
}
td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .left2, .main2 {
        width: 100%;
    }
    thead {
        display: none;
    }
    td {
        display: block;
    }
    td:first-child {
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
    }
    td:nth-child(1)::before {
        content: "Repair Type"
    }
    td {
        text-align: center;
    }
    td::before {
        float: left;
    }
}
```

```html
           <table>
               <thead>
                   <tr>
                   <th>Repair Type</th>
                   <th>Price</th>
                   <th>Turnaround Time</th>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
                   <tr>
                       <td>Battery Replacement</td>
                       <td>$50 - $100</td>
                       <td>Same Day</td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <td>Camera Replacement</td>
                       <td>$30 - $105</td>
                       <td>Same Day</td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <td>Charging Port Repair</td>
                       <td>$25 - $100</td>
                       <td>Same Day</td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <td>Diagnostic</td>
                       <td>Free</td>
                       <td>Same Day</td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <td>Ear Piece Replacement</td>
                       <td>$80</td>
                       <td>Same Day</td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <td>Home Button Replacement - Select Models Only</td>
                       <td>$50 - $150</td>
                       <td>Same Day</td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <td>Screen Repair</td>
                       <td>$30 - $150</td>
                       <td>Same Day</td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <td>Water Damage Repair</td>
                       <td>$50 - $150</td>
                       <td>Same Day</td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <td>Virus Removal</td>
                       <td>$80</td>
                       <td>Same Day</td>
                   </tr>
               </tbody>
           </table>
```

Comment: overflow-x : scroll

Answer (score 0):

you can use the @media query for the table

```
.table-responsive {
    min-height: .01%;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .table-responsive {
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
    .table-responsive > .table {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .table-responsive > .table > thead > tr > th,
    .table-responsive > .table > tbody > tr > th,
    .table-responsive > .table > tfoot > tr > th,
    .table-responsive > .table > thead > tr > td,
    .table-responsive > .table > tbody > tr > td,
    .table-responsive > .table > tfoot > tr > td {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
}
```

what it does is that it looks for the display size and once a certain size is reached it triggers the CSS relative to that screen size, this is completely user-defined and you can modify it however you want